# Shaka Player Start Video in full screen

Tags: shaka

I have the basic shaka player code. I want to start the video on full screen. Please tell me if it is possible.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
  <head>
    <!-- Shaka Player compiled library: -->
    <script src="dist/shaka-player.compiled.js"></script>
    <!-- Your application source: -->
    <script src="myapp.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="height:100%">
    <video id="video"
           width="100%"
           height="100%"
           poster="//shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/assets/poster.jpg"
           controls autoplay></video>
  </body>
</html>
```

**myapp.js**

```
// myapp.js

var manifestUri =
    './asd.mp4';

function initApp() {
  // Install built-in polyfills to patch browser incompatibilities.
  shaka.polyfill.installAll();

  // Check to see if the browser supports the basic APIs Shaka needs.
  if (shaka.Player.isBrowserSupported()) {
    // Everything looks good!
    initPlayer();
  } else {
    // This browser does not have the minimum set of APIs we need.
    console.error('Browser not supported!');
  }
}

function initPlayer() {
  // Create a Player instance.
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var player = new shaka.Player(video);

  // Attach player to the window to make it easy to access in the JS console.
  window.player = player;

  // Listen for error events.
  player.addEventListener('error', onErrorEvent);

  // Try to load a manifest.
  // This is an asynchronous process.
  player.load(manifestUri).then(function() {
    // This runs if the asynchronous load is successful.
    console.log('The video has now been loaded!');
  }).catch(onError);  // onError is executed if the asynchronous load fails.
}

function onErrorEvent(event) {
  // Extract the shaka.util.Error object from the event.
  onError(event.detail);
}

function onError(error) {
  // Log the error.
  console.error('Error code', error.code, 'object', error);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initApp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this using the below code

```
player.load(manifestUri).then(function() {
    // This runs if the asynchronous load is successful.
    console.log('The video has now been loaded!');
    video.requestFullscreen().catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    });
  }).catch(onError);  // onError is executed if the asynchronous load fails.
```

Please let me know if there is a better solution